# using C# DLL in IronRuby

Tags: c#, .net, sharpdevelop, ironruby

I using C# DLL ServiceStack.redis in IronRuby. Form Designer was SharpDevelop. the code is:

```
    require 'redis/ServiceStack.Redis' # redis is subfolder in project
    ...
    def Button1Click(sender, e)
          object =  ServiceStack::Redis.PooledRedisClientManager.new
    end
```

and the error message was:

```
System.MissingMethodException: undefined method `PooledRedisClientManager' for ServiceStack::Redis:Module
```

but in dotPeek, I can see the C# code was:

```
namespace ServiceStack.Redis
{
  public class PooledRedisClientManager
 {
   ...
    public PooledRedisClientManager()
      : this("localhost")
    {
    }
 }
}
```

How can I import the C# DLL and use in IronRuby ?

Answer (score 1):

OK the problem solved.

the keywords are: require path, name change.

I tried to make a C# DLL file look like:

```
  namespace testdll
  {
      public class MyClass
      {
          public MyClass()
          {
              Console.Writeln("run test dll");
          }
      }
  }
```

and the DLL name was: testdll.dll
in IronRuby project, the code I wrote:

```
    require "testdll"
    obj = testdll::MyClass.new
```

that was failed. because Module name of Ruby's first letter must be capitalized.

so I modified the testdll namespace to:

```
namespace TestDll
```

then the code in IR was:

```
obj = TestDll::MyClass.new
```

it's past.

then I think maybe ServiceStack.Redis was a "wrong" Module name ? so I tried:

```
  namespace Test.Dll # in C#
  ...
  obj = Test.Dll::MyClass.new
```

failed.
at that time I thought that I need to Wrap the ServiceStack.Redis to something like:

```
   namespace Wrap
   {
       public class Redis : ServiceStack.Redis.SomeClass ...
   }
```

but it's too complicated to be done and I view the original code in IR,
and I found the code:

```
  require "System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
  require "System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```

and we can use :
System::Drawing::Point ...
so I view the System.Drawing DLL in dotPeek, I found the code familiar just like ServiceStack.xxx

```
  namespace System.Drawing
```

so if we can use the code System::Drawing with namespace System.Drawing， why my code will fail ?
I tried changed require code from:

```
   require "redis/ServiceStack.redis" to 
   require "ServiceStack.redis"
```

then:

```
   object = ServiceStack::Redis::PooledRedisClientManager.new
```

....
Past !
important things are:

1. do not require C# DLL with path related.
2. in IR namespace A.B in C# DLL will rename module name to A::B